# Exposure classes

Tags: java, class, if-statement

Soo, I tried to write the code when one class acts with each other class. Here are class warior with "Tim" and class witcher with "Max". The console should speak  "Now Max hp.. 50" or "Now Tim's hp.. 50 hp", but console sayed "Now Max hp.. 25" or "Now Tim's hp.. 25 hp".. 75 - 25 = 50; 100-50=50; but sayed 75 - 25 = 25; 100-50=25;
Help please :c

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MAXvsTIMvoidVersion {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    warior Tim = new warior();
    Tim.agility = 100;
    Tim.attack = 25;
    Tim.hp = 100;
    Tim.Wariorlvl2 = true;

    witcher Max = new witcher();
    Max.mana = 150;
    Max.attack = 50;
    Max.hp = 75;
    Max.Witcherlvl1 = true;

    Random a = new Random();
    int b = a.nextInt(2);

            if (b == 0)
            {
                Tim.meleeAttack();
                System.out.print("Now Max's hp.." + Max.hp);
            }

            else if (b == 1)
            {
                Max.magicAttack();
                System.out.print("Now Tim's hp.." + Tim.hp);
            }
    }

}


class people
{
    static int hp;
    static int attack;
}

class witcher extends people
{
    int mana;
    boolean Witcherlvl1;
    boolean Witcherlvl2;
    void magicAttack()
    {
        warior.hp = warior.hp - witcher.attack;
        mana = mana - 20;
    }
}

class warior extends people
{
    int agility;
    boolean Wariorlvl1;
    boolean Wariorlvl2;
    void meleeAttack()
    {
        witcher.hp = witcher.hp - warior.attack;
        agility = agility - 20;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) are: Class names start with a capital letter and variable names start with a lowercase letter. If you use those conventions the code becomes easier to read for the average programmer and also the code markup on this site works better that way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class People
{
    static int hp = 0;
    static int attack = 0;
}
```

Look at the above code. It tells that hp and attack are part of people class and are static. So, Warrior and Witcher get the same copies [ read shared/same ] from People. So, the following piece of code

```
warior Tim = new warior();
Tim.agility = 100;
Tim.attack = 25;
Tim.hp = 100;
Tim.Wariorlvl2 = true;

witcher Max = new witcher();
Max.mana = 150;
Max.attack = 50;
Max.hp = 75;
Max.Witcherlvl1 = true;
```

gives an over-written effect by setting the attack to 50. So, in `meleeAttack()` or `magicAttack()`, you end up subtracting 50 instead of the appropriate value.

To understand more, try setting Max.attack = 0;

Also, you should be passing the reference of the victim in `meleeAttack()` or `magicAttack()` which gives much clarity. Something like

```
void magicAttack( Warrior warrior );
```

I would suggest you to remove the static modifiers from your People class. That should do the trick as with it, Warrior and Witcher would end up with their own copies of the variables.

Comment: would it not be better to approach this using OOP?

Comment: @AbtPst I do not quite follow what you are trying to convey. The core of the problem is to remove the static modifiers and allow inheritance to go smooth which itself is OOP feature.

Comment: yeah, i just thought another approach can be build the classes in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

how about this structure

People class with common features of Warrior and Witcher

```
class People
{
    int attack;
    int hp;
}
```

Warrior class

```
class Warrior extends People
{

  int agility;
  boolean Warriorlvl2;

  Warrior(int at, int hitp)
  {
    attack = at;
    hp = hitp;
  }

  void meleeAttack(People opponent)
  {
    opponent.hp = opponent.hp - this.attack;
  }
}
```

Witcher class

```
class Witcher extends People
{
  int mana;
  boolean Witcherlvl1;

  Witcher(int at, int hitp)
 {
    attack = at;
    hp = hitp;
  }

  void magicAttack(People opponent)
  {
    opponent.hp = opponent.hp - this.attack;
  }
}
```

then you can have a main class as

```
public class MAXvsTIMvoidVersion {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Warrior Tim = new Warrior(25,100);
    Tim.agility = 100;
    Tim.Wariorlvl2 = true;

    Witcher Max = new Witcher(50,75);
    Max.mana = 150;
    Max.Witcherlvl1 = true;

    Random a = new Random();
    int b = a.nextInt(2);

            if (b == 0)
            {
                Tim.meleeAttack(Max);
                System.out.print("Now Max's hp.." + Max.hp);
            }

            else if (b == 1)
            {
                Max.magicAttack(Tim);
                System.out.print("Now Tim's hp.." + Tim.hp);
            }
    }

}
```

in this way, with object oriented approach, it is fairly easy to implement the behavior you want. read through the code and try to understand. if you have trouble understanding, i can guide you.

Comment: I think Panan's answer is to easy then your answer. But I tried your cod and this is work too

Comment: cool, i just wanted to show th object oriented approach. happy coding :)